# can i get some help drawing a polarization ellipse, something like this:

Tags: tikz-pgf, physics

Need help drawing this in tikz please.

[image]

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, the code in my comment was not quite right. It had a typo and the bounding box was not as tight as I thought it would be. (Note to myself: don't write Ti*k*Z code on an iPad, especially when it has auto-correction. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[dashed] 
 \draw (0,4) node[right]{$y$} -- (0,-4);
 \draw (5,0) node[above]{$x$} -- (-5,0);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[rotate=30] 
 \draw (0,0) circle (4 and 2); 
 \draw (0,4) node[left]{$y'$} --  (0,-4) node[pos=0.35,right]{$b$};
 \draw (5.5,0) node[above]{$x'$} -- (-5.5,0) node[pos=0.4,above]{$a$};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=elli,rotate=30] 
 \path plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,samples=360] ({4*cos(\t)},{2*sin(\t)}); 
\end{scope}
\draw (elli.south west) rectangle (elli.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with an analytic determination of the bounding box.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=4;b=2;alpha=30;}]
\begin{scope}[dashed] 
 \draw (0,5*b/3) node[right]{$y$} -- (0,-5*b/3);
 \draw (4*a/3,0) node[above]{$x$} -- (-4*a/3,0);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[rotate=alpha] 
 \draw (0,0) circle (a and b); 
 \draw (0,5*b/3) node[left]{$y'$} --  (0,-5*b/3) node[pos=0.35,right]{$b$};
 \draw (4*a/3,0) node[above]{$x'$} -- (-4*a/3,0) node[pos=0.4,above]{$a$};
 \path 
 ({a*cos(atan(-(b/a)*tan(alpha)))},{b*sin(atan(-(b/a)*tan(alpha)))}) coordinate (aux1)
 ({a*cos(atan((b/a)*cot(alpha)))},{b*sin(atan((b/a)*cot(alpha)))}) coordinate (aux2) 
 ({-a*cos(atan(-(b/a)*tan(alpha)))},{-b*sin(atan(-(b/a)*tan(alpha)))}) coordinate (aux3)
 ({-a*cos(atan((b/a)*cot(alpha)))},{-b*sin(atan((b/a)*cot(alpha)))}) coordinate (aux4); 
\end{scope}
\draw (aux3|-aux4) rectangle (aux1|-aux2);
\path (0:1) coordinate (A) (0,0) coordinate[label={[xshift=0.3em]below left:{$O$}}] (O)
 (alpha:1) coordinate (C) 
pic ["$\Psi$",draw,latex-latex,angle radius=1.8cm,angle eccentricity=1.2] {angle = A--O--C};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank marmot! I didn't know that we can define a constant by 'declare function'

Comment: @BlackMild I have seen this at various places. (And it is not too surprising, is it?) Note, however, that there is a drawback: it is not at all straightforward to "undefine" functions (which is one of the reasons why I made the definition local, i.e. set them in the `tikzpicture`).

Comment: and tikz code looks better with a,b instead of \a,\b

Comment: this is great, thank you! how would i label the sides of the rectangles?

Comment: @easychachi In the second code you could add `\path (aux3|-aux2) -- (aux1|-aux2) node[pos=0.5,above,fill=white] {$w$}
(aux1|-aux2) -- (aux1|-aux4) node[pos=0.5,right,fill=white] {$h$};`. BTW, if you have a new question, even if it is a follow-up question, the rules of the site say that you should ask a new question. And if an answer solves your problem, you may consider accepting it by clicking on the check mark left of it.